# What does * HTML Body mean in a css style sheet?

Tags: css, syntax

In a stylesheet i have:

```
    * HTML BODY
    {
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        padding-top: 190px;
    }
    * HTML #maincontent
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

i know that a . means class and a # means applied to the id, but what does * HTML mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The * is the universal selector, and thus matches any element. e.g.

```
P * { }
```

Matches any element which is the child of a P tag

```
* HTML
```

should mean nothing because HTML cannot be the child of anything (by definition). It's used because IE (edit, at least IE 5 - 6 - thanks RoBorg!) ignores * and so it can be used to define IE specific styles:

```
HTML {
 // Normal styles
}

* HTML {
 // IE Specific styles
 }
```

See http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=358552

Comment: Cool, thanks.. I hadn't written but was given it to use in a template and just wanted to understand why it was used before blindly adding it.

Comment: It's sometimes used to enforce certain rules across your whole document, such as a default fonts-size, font, or color. Keep in rules with an * should be used at the beginning of your css document as its scope it your full document. Hence all conflicting styles with previously declared selectors would be overwritten (cascading rule of css)

Answer (score 4):

`*` means any element
`HTML` and `BODY` mean the `<html>` and `<body>` elements.

Therefore `* HTML BODY` means a body element inside an HTML element, inside any element.

This is actually a **browser hack**: some browsers will match it and some won't (Internet Explorer matches, Firefox doesn't, not sure about others).

Answer (score 2):

One reason people add selectors like  *, html, or body (or in this case, all 3) to a stylesheet rule is to increase the selector specificity calculation.  Of course, html will never be a child of anything else, so * html is a specific IE hack, but there is a reason why people would add html or body to a declaration:

For example:

```
html p { font-color: red }
p { font-color: blue }
```

Paragraphs within html tags (as in, all of them) is more specific than just paragraphs, so the font-color will be red, regardless of the ordering of these declarations in stylesheets.   If there were a third rule with html body p it would take precedence.

It's slightly less of a hack than using !important but it's better to key off of more semantic tags, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a really bad CSS selector statement, that's what.  Let me break it down for you:

```
[all elements] (sub-selection) [HTML] [BODY]
```

That is, it goes through all elements to find the `HTML` element, then the `BODY` inside.  It's problem is that there will only be *1* body element at all times, and `#maincontent` either should be the `BODY` or be within it.  Period.

As Joel said it might be to remind the designer, but I am not so sure of that.  To me, that code is a definite "code smell"!

You should rewrite your CSS selectors to:

```
body {
```

And:

```
#maincontent {
```

respectively.

Comment: It is code smell, but that's because it's a compatability hack for IE

Answer (score -2):

For the 2nd snippet, since * matches anything the element item is redundant.  It looks like it's there to remind the author of the intent of the styles- that if he changes something in the 2nd snippet make sure he checks the #maincontent element to make sure it looks right.

Comment: It's not redundant.  It should mean that HTML is a child of some other element.  Under the interpretation of most browsers, that is not the case.  But in IE HTML is a child of some mysterious uber-element.

Comment: Oops: for some reason I was reading those as if there were a comma between them! :(